# Uniformly convex but not strongly convex function

Tags: convex-analysis

As we know, the [uniformly convex function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Uniformly_convex_functions) is a generalization of the strongly convex function. However, is there any example that belongs to the former, not the latter? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. $f(x)=x^2$ is strongly convex.
2. $f(x)=x^3$ on $[0,1]$ is uniformly convex but not strongly.
3. $f(x)=e^x$ strictly convex but not uniformly convex.
4. $f(x)=|x|$ is convex but not strictly convex.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these nice examples. BTW: Is there any example defined on R instead of on an interval as in 2?

Comment: @kaienfr: Yes, there is. You just have to extend $f(x)=x^3$ with $x^2$